# Hashing passwords in ASP.NET membership

Tags: asp.net, hash, passwords, membership

I have this ASP.NET application that is running fine. Now I need to add users to the ASP.NET membership database from a Windows Forms application. I’ve been able to use the Membership classes from inside the Windows forms app successfully, but it takes too long to add a user and I have to add a large amount of users.

So, I´ve been trying to add those users directly to the database, but can´t get the passwords hashed correctly.

Here is the code I’m using to generate the hashed passwords:

```
public static string EncodePassword2(string pass, out string saltb64)
{
    saltb64 = Crypto.GenerateSalt();
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pass);
    byte[] src = Convert.FromBase64String(saltb64);
    byte[] dst = new byte[src.Length + bytes.Length];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(src, 0, dst, 0, src.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, dst, src.Length, bytes.Length);
    HashAlgorithm algorithm = HashAlgorithm.Create("HMACSHA256");
    byte[] inArray = algorithm.ComputeHash(dst);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(inArray);
}
```

Does anyone know how to do this the right way?

Answer (score 0):

Use  **Crypto.HashPassword** method

Refer this link:

http://www.troyhunt.com/2012/07/stronger-password-hashing-in-net-with.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Troy is wrong about the hash algorithm asp.net team is using, if you see comments on that page you´ll see that, as is stated in that same post the algorithm used is HMACSHA256. I've tested both and they are not working. If you could provide some example code it would be great.